# understanding P4 describe / diff summary (-ds) option

Tags: diff, perforce

Greetings P4 folks,

I am trying to understand the P4 describe -ds output. I am assuming that this is the same as the p4 diff -ds output.

Here is an example of the "Differences ..." block:

==== //depot/Groups/mygroup/trunk/main/FooBar.java#5 (text) ====


add 7 chunks 13 lines

deleted 1 chunks 1 lines

changed 16 chunks 92 / 118 lines

~

Now I understand that add and deleted lines are clear but why are there two numbers for the changed lines (92 / 118).

Thanks!

- JsD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are the number of lines before and after the change, within the changed chunks. In other words, 92 lines were changed across 16 locations to become 118 lines of code.

Comment: Thanks Jason. Just revisited my code and was thankful to find your answer. Sorry I did not flag as answered sooner ;)